# How to initialize context in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an annoying problem I wanted to use custom dialog in recycler view adapter but I need a context for builder and I wrote that but I can't initialized that. I looked up Internet but I can't find anything. Is anyone can help me? Thank you and have a good codes :)

```
private lateinit var context: Context
```

Adapter class

```
class MainAdapter(private val cityList: List<City>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    class ViewHolder(binding: CityCardBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        val cityBinding : CityCardBinding = binding
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = CityCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
        
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val city = cityList[position]
        holder.cityBinding.cityCard = city

        holder.cityBinding.cardCity.setOnClickListener {
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = cityList.size
}
```

Comment: add in the code which you have tried.

Comment: you should send context of activity in your adapter constructor. when you initialize your adapter in activity/fragment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As a best practice keep your dialog logic in the activity. Get the activity context in adapter and then with this context call the dialog function present in the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do it.

****1.** Very simple one, pass in the constructor.**

You could pass the context via your adapter constructor, something
like this.

In **Adapter** you could write:

```
class MyAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    fun doSomething() {
        mContext = context
    }
}
```

In your **Activity/Fragment**:

```
private fun bindAdapter() {
    val adapter = MyAdapter(context = this)  // Use requireActivity() for fragments
}
```

**2. Use Dependency Injection to inject context. For example [Dagger Hilt](https://github.com/square/Dagger)**

**3. You can use any view to get context.**

In your case for example, `holder.cityBinding.cardCity.context` this will also give you context

***Suggestion:***

My suggestion to you is, if anything like dialog you want to show then use activity/fragment for that, whole UI logic should be in activity/fragment to go with architecture standards.

If your requirement is Anything like you want to show particular data of one item of adapter inside dialog then on click of that button you can take a callback with your selected item data to the activity/fragment and show dialog there with data.

Hope this help!!!

Comment: Yeah I know, I can add with constructor but I don't prefer that I was trying any other method. Btw I added my adapter class

Answer (score 0):

1- From here you can pass Context like i am sending **myContext** From Activity/Faragment

```
        binding.rvIssues.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(myContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        val adapterIssue = AdapterIssues(myContext, messagesList)
        binding.rvIssues.adapter = adapterIssue
```

2 - In Adapter you can put keyWord **var**  to globalise the scope of context and can be use any where in Adapter

```
class AdapterIssues(
var context: Context,
var messagesList: ArrayList<ResourceModel>,
var listener: SetOnIssueItemClickListener) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterIssues.ViewHolder>() {}
```

3- you don't need to put in adapter  like

private lateinit var context: Context